# Web Performance API includes fileSize?

Tags: javascript, performance, dom

i just started to create RUM script:

im using window.performance javaScript object

```
window.addEventListener('unload', logData, false);
function logData()
{
    var body = {};
    body.timestamp = Date.now();
    body.operatingSystem = navigator.platform;
    body.userAgent = navigator.userAgent;
    body.performance = performance.timing;
    var blob = new Blob([JSON.stringify(body)], {type : 'application/json; charset=UTF-8'});
    navigator.sendBeacon('https://stage.bitsngo.com/rum', blob);
}
```

in server side im save it to DB.

the question is, if i can get for each file this information +  file size.

for example:
[image]

(file size must be obtained because time measurement without file size is not equal)

Comment: i found the answer, some of the browsers didnot implemented yet some of the attributes(file size, transfer size).